# How to select a row in Pandas Dataframe based on searching a data in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a query related to DataFrames of Pandas library. 
Let, I have a dataframe like this:

```
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Chris',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food',
                        'Cost': 22.50})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Kevyn',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter',
                        'Cost': 2.50})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Vinod',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Bird Seed',
                        'Cost': 5.00})

df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3], index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

I want to find out, who purchased the item cost maximum or, WHO PURCHASED DOG FOOD. Basically I want to find a single data in a single column, then I want to select the entire row. I want to extract any data from any columns of that selected row. What is the most pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want select one row DataFrame use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and compare max value:

```
df1 = df[df['Cost'] == df['Cost'].max()]
print (df1)
          Name Item Purchased  Cost
Store 1  Chris       Dog Food  22.5
```

Or if want name by maximum `Cost` create index by `Name` column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
a = df.set_index('Name')['Cost'].idxmax()
print (a)
Chris
```

For filter by `Dog Food`:

```
df2 = df[df['Item Purchased'] == 'Dog Food']
print (df2)
          Name Item Purchased  Cost
Store 1  Chris       Dog Food  22.5
```

If want only `Name` by filtered rows - first matched value with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - output is `Series`, one or more values:

```
s = df.loc[df['Item Purchased'] == 'Dog Food', 'Name']
print (s)
Store 1    Chris
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Then select first value:

```
print (s[0])
Chris
```

But if value not exist then is returned empty `Series`:

```
s = df.loc[df['Item Purchased'] == 'Cat Food', 'Name']
print (s)
Series([], Name: Name, dtype: object)
```

So is necessary use alternative solution for select with `next` and `iter` for default value if no value filtered:

```
print (next(iter(s), 'no match'))
no match
```

Comment: If I want to find out who purchased dog food, how should I do that?